# How can I have line breaks in my long latex equations?

Tags: align

How can I have line breaks in my long latex equations where I have used `align`?
[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A + B + C&= \begin{aligned}[t]
 a + b & + c + d\\
       & + e + f
            \end{aligned}\\
&= \begin{aligned}[t]
 a' + b' & + c' + d'\\
         & + e' + f'
            \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]